# Selenium unable to reach login page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


def main(driver):
    driver.get('https://account.t-mobile.com/signin/')
    waiter = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

    try:
        waiter.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.ID, 'usernameTextBox'))).send_keys("test@test.com")
        driver.find_element_by_id("lp1-next-btn").click()

    except TimeoutException as e:
        print(repr(e))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = Options()
    options.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    main(driver)
```

I'm unable to land to the login page as it's keep loads forever when am using selenium.

[image]

Even i tried with [Chrome](https://replit.com/@AmericanY/LoginIssue) which is leading to same scenario.

Answer (score 0):

looks like some issue with Firefox form application side.

I tried switching to chrome and it did work.

**Code :**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

executablePath= r'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe'

def main(driver):
    driver.get('https://account.t-mobile.com/signin/')
    waiter = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

    try:
        waiter.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.ID, 'usernameTextBox'))).send_keys("test@test.com")
        driver.find_element_by_id("lp1-next-btn").click()

    except TimeoutException as e:
        print(repr(e))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
   # options.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = executablePath, options=options)
    main(driver)
```

You can get a latest chromedriver from [official website here](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/)

Comment: I've tried with Chrome before asking this question as well. it's keep displaying a loading page which never finish. even i tried from different location with different GEO. would you please show me a gif for the landing page which you reached ?